# Enforce enum namespace as method parameter

Tags: c#, interface, enums

I'm working on a logging framework that will send hierarchical metrics to a Graphite server (represented as strings separated by dots, e.g., "site.login_page.page_load"). To keep naming consistent across several teams, developers shouldn't be able to send free-form text, since it will potentially impact metrics aggregation by having different namespaces. My initial thoughts are to use an enum:

```
public enum WaitingRoomMetrics
    {
        CheckIn,
        WaitTime
    }
}

LogTimeMetricInMs (WaitingRoomMetrics.CheckIn, 900000);
```

This would prevent developers from creating inconsistent free-form metrics like this:

```
LogTimeMetricInMs ("waiting_room.checkin", 300000);
LogTimeMetricInMs ("waitingroom.TotalwaitTime", 900000);
```

Currently, my interface definition for LogTimeInMetrics is:

```
interface LogTimeInMetrics (Enum metric, long timeInMs);
```

While developers could create their own enums, it doesn't really solve the problem of enforcing consistency. Ideally, I'd like to have a different Nuget package for each discrete component that has all metrics available for that application component.  Developers can then install the Nuget packages for any metrics they need to expose. However, enums still feel a bit simplistic and they still give developers too much free reign, unless we provide enforcement at the code check-in/pull request review.

Basically, I'm looking to have a Metrics.Base package which would contain some kind of a base type that has built-in validation. All metrics would need to inherit from that base clase. The interface would then look like:

```
 interface LogTimeInMetrics (BaseMetric metric, long timeInMs);
```

But it feels like building a separate class for each metric is overkill and could be an administrative nightmare--basically each metric is just a "ToString()". Is there a better model to manage a large list of basically Enum-type values managed across several Nuget packages, provide Intellisense and some sense of namespace/naming convention enforcement/validation? Or forego Intellisense and just maintain a collection of constants?

Comment: What's wrong with const strings?

Comment: My concern is that if the metric parameter is a string, then a developer could simply hardcode a metric name directly in the call. I'm trying to make that difficult, if not impossible to do.